# Android - update other tab content from tab

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a trouble . Can someone show me the way!

I have 3 tabs : A TAB, B TAB, C TAB
A TAB : list all movie file 
B TAB : list all downloading file 
...

When i select a file or multiple files in A TAB it will add it automatic to B TAB.
How can I do it !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ListView and list adapter for B tab, You can add item to the list adapter. You can have some global singleton object and share data (lists, adapters) between tabs.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the selected files from TAB A in a local database (or a file, or a static variable, or whatever you want...), and access them when initializing the TAB B.